# C# Application unknown crash to the customer

Tags: c#, crash, bug-reporting

I'm developing an application in Visual Studio 2010, in C#, on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.
The app properties tells that it uses .Net Framework 4.0.

I have made videos on how to use the app, and never found it crashing. So i sent the app to the customer for who i was making the app. He said that he was following step by step the videos, but the app crashes on his Windows 7. I have tried installing on the Windows 7, and didn't found any crash, no crash at all.

What may be the reason for this? Might be his windows installation corrupted? because here tested on 2 different computers, one win 8.1, and the other one win 7 never had a crash. Only he is having the app crashing. 
I also took a look at the crash reports he sent me, and those are all unreferenced to my app.

Second question: How can i make something like professional apps, which when crashes opens a dialog Bug Report, and give the possibility of sending the crash error with all files as attachment to the developers?

Comment: Forgetting to write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is a standard oversight.

Answer (score -2):

Before install the app.Try to disable your antivirus software.